# Why does @font-face not work in IE8?

Tags: html

Does anybody have an idea, why this one does not work in IE8?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'entypo';
    src: url('styles/fonts/entypo/entypo_normal.eot');
    src: url('styles/fonts/entypo/entypo_normal.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('styles/fonts/entypo/entypo_normal.woff') format('woff'),
        url('styles/fonts/entypo/entypo_normal.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('styles/fonts/entypo/entypo_normal.eot#entypo_normal') format('svg');

    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

It is included at the top of the `<head>` of `index.html`. It works in IE10 and Chrome, so the paths should be correct.

I run IE8 in a VM.

Comment: I think this is CSS3, and IE8 doesn't support it

Comment: According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=font-face), IE8 does support it.

Comment: @bksi font-face is supported by IE8: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface in a buggy way but it's supported. The problem must be caused by font files

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in a pure IE8 browser? Perhaps the VM screws the normal behaviour....

Comment: it supports it as kraftwer1 mentioned, one thing that can be wrong is the font file itself... try searching for a better one... one place to start would be here [link]http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator
find a good .ttf font file and convert it to all of the rest font file types

Comment: Hm here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(Cascading_Style_Sheets) it says that font-face is supported from 9.0 and up

Comment: @bksi IE7 and IE8 supports SOME CSS3 properties (for example, @font-face). Wikipedia is not a CSS3 manual...

Comment: When using `@font-face`, IE8 and earlier only supports the [EOT format](http://caniuse.com/#feat=eot). Any investigation of the font files should start with the EOT file: `url('styles/fonts/entypo/entypo_normal.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')`. The syntax looks correct, but the file itself might be missing or corrupt.

Comment: The d=syntax looks good except for the svg font which you have pointing to the eot one `url('styles/fonts/entypo/entypo_normal.eot#entypo_normal') format('svg')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is good, I would look at the font file itself.

Did you use a conversion tool? Try converting the font again.

Check to see if you can access the EOT file directly (should be fine if it works in IE9).

Are there any CSS classes targeting IE8? Check to see if they are changing the font family.

Comment: You are right, the `.eot` was broken. I didn't use a converter, somebody mailed them to me. Do you know any converter that I can use locally, since I'm not allowed to upload "non-free" fonts to FontSquirrel (for conversion)?

Comment: I use FontSquirrel aswell for this kind of things. You should take/find another font or find a site that will let you convert the right font. And if you did find one, I would love to hear it aswell!